# Tableau converting dimension to measure

Tags: tableau-api, dimension, measure

I have a technical question relating to Tableau. I have a Category field in the dimensions section which has three indicators: Disposable Income, GDP and Consumer Expenditure. I would like to convert 'Disposable Income' into a measure value on its own.

Is this possible to do?

[image: snapshot]

I cannot share the Tableau data source due to data restrictions.

Comment: where have you stored your original data? Excel or text file or some other source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate solution to your problem I propose here, but it needs reshaping your data altogether.  I have created a sample data for explanation like this

[image: input sample untidy data]

select three years column and click on pivot.. you will get a view like this after renaming the fields appropriately

[image: half tidy data]

From here you can proceed as described above.

Comment: @francois, It will be better if you can reshape your data before any visualization

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, yes I know that reshaping the data could be an alternative, however I was hoping to sidestep this method :)

Comment: So the solution doesn't serve your purpose?

Comment: Well it does but I was simply looking for an alternative. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy.  Add  a calculated field named `Disposable Income` as-

```
IF [category] = 'Disposable Income' THEN [Measure_Val] END
```

Needless to say `[Measure_val]` is your measure field name here.

Comment: Thank you very much, @AnilGoyal. I will try this out!

Comment: Hi Anil, so in this case [Measure_val] would be 'Disposable Income' or something else?

Comment: No! [Measure val] is your measure name that you want to show against `disposable income`

Comment: OK, not really sure now what to do. Would you be able to provide an example, please?

Comment: In that case please provide me a snapshot of your data/sample data! May be I'm wrong?

Comment: Hi Anil, please check out the image here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405484/how-can-i-convert-a-dimension-into-a-measure-in-tableau

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  You didn't need to create a new question just to upload a screenshot.  You can edit this question.  Nevertheless i will edit it here.  Now When I got your problem understood, please tell me which measure out of the three values like `2019`, `2020` or `2021` you want against your disposable income? If you want any one chose that as `measure_val`.  If you want all three, then you l need three calculated fields.  Or alternatively you can reshape your data altogether, but you'll need tableau prep for that.

Comment: Actually your data isn't tidy.  Variable values are entered as value names instead.

Comment: @FrancoisRa, see point no.7 of https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/02/lod-uses.html