# How can I convert a dimension into a measure in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, dimension

[Snapshot of Tableau interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUIxO.png)

I have a technical question relating to Tableau. I have a Category field in the dimensions section which has three indicators: Disposable Income, GDP and Consumer Expenditure. I would like to convert 'Disposable Income' into a measure value on its own. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tableau converting dimension to measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384543/tableau-converting-dimension-to-measure)

Comment: A far better way to handle problems like this is to restructure the data before importing into tableau. Something like City, Time period, GDP, Consumer Expenditure, disposable Income all as separate columns. This will make analysis in Tableau far easier. Some of this can be done by pivoting in tableau, but it is better to restructure before importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can but I am not sure why you would want to do that. I guess I need to understand the context a bit more.

To convert Disposable Income into a measure:

1. create a calculated field with the below values:
   name: Disposable Income
   formula: IF [Category] = "Disposable Income" THEN [Category] END
2. right click on the new Disposable Income field you created and select convert to measure.

Measures are supposed to be things that you can aggregate e.g. sum, average etc. so if you put a string as a measure it will by default create a count distinct of that field which you can change.

Comment: Probably you are erring somewhere, you cannot convert a dimension to measure unless you aggregate it to count or min/max.  Because your calculated field will return value as string `disposable income` instead of income's value.  In that case we have to map it with measure_value as I have suggested

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Well there are many reasons. One is that I find it easier to do certain calculations (for example, per capita disposable income or disposable income growth over a certain period). So this is a key reason why I want to convert dimensions into measures. Maybe there are ways to go about this without converting the data, but I would need to learn that too!

Comment: @FrancoisRa to do what you want, it will be better to create a new measure and say: IF [Category] = "Disposable Income" THEN [MeasureNameYouWant] END. Replace MeasureNameYouWant with the name of the measure you want and this will work fine.